# Meson conservation

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, mesons

Why meson conservation doesn't exist?

Comment: Asking more than one question per thread is agains the rules, you should ask only one.

Comment: In this country I have to sleep now...
So, I don't have enough time for 3hours for asking 4 question...
I'm so sorry...

Comment: The question will probably be closed until you fix it. You can do it whenever you want. These are very broad questions and they need more than one post to get answered well enough all.

Comment: I edit my answer... too sad

Comment: I can hardly understand the question(s). How could this meson exist? Isn't that a question for god? The difference to lambda and sigma can easily be looked up on wikipedia.

Comment: umm... I was wondering form of this messon.
and there is u(anti u) in this formula
so how can this thing happen

I can't see this in wikipedia ...
Can you give me some url?

Comment: oh I found it from related question... thank you..

Comment: Ask **seperate** questions.  Do not keep editing the same post to ask different questions in each edit.  If you found an answer in a related question then please close this question.

Comment: Sorry .. I just erase the question that I found during 40 min...

Comment: Is the question about baryon number conservation? Mesons also conserve baryon number...

Answer (score 2):

Perusing the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov), the fountainhead of all particle knowledge, or a half-decent HEP text, you can find out *how* mesons decay to answer your question. Essentially they are $\bar q q$ quark composites, so their constituents can:

1. Combine with more $\bar q q$  pairs emergent out of the glue soup of QCD, and strongly decay to more mesons, like $\rho \to \pi \pi$, if they are sufficiently heavy; or weakly like $K^+\to \pi^+ \pi^0$.
2. If they are neutral and their quarks are of the same flavor, they may decay to photons, electromagnetically, like $\pi^0\to \gamma \gamma$.
3. If their quarks are of different flavor, they weakly decay to whatever the intermediating virtual *W* bosons decay to, so lepton-antilepton pairs, or mesons with different flavors.

So there is hardly a reason for them to conserve an over-all or particular meson number: $\bar q q$ pairs are slated for annihilation or instability. ***All mesons decay***.

Comment: I wonder that baryon is as unstable as meson.
But, there is baryon conservation law.
Could you tell me what is difference between them?

Comment: Most baryons are unstable and decay similarly, except for the lightest ones (*p*, and under special circumstances, *n*). Consisting of three quarks, there is nothing with which the quarks could annihilate, so they are protected by the so-called conserved [baryon/quark number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number). In some highly speculative theories such as GUTs, this number is not conserved, and all baryons decay (seldomly), a process never observed, so far...

Comment: I just saw wiki which meson and baryon's exist time are similar.
Than I want to know why there is only baryon conservation.
Mr said mesons are too unstable so there isn't meson conservation.
Did I get it right? Than... why there isn't exist meson conservation......

Comment: As I said, baryons have a B=1, so it cannot go away, but mesons have B=0, so it is the same whether they are there or gone... This is what HEP books drill into you.